# Why Special Characters dont show in my pdf in latex

Tags: latex

i have a problem outputing special characthers in latex even tho im using latin packages

Comment: Please make a [mre] that shows us which characters you want to use. Please also state which engine you are using, e.g. pdflatex, xelatex, lualatex or something else?

Comment: im using overleaf.com and the special charachters are é à è ç

Comment: Please make a [mre]. These characters normally work without problem.

Comment: You may possibly switch to xelatex or lualatex in Overleaf. I am sure you can find that on the Northwest corner.

Answer (score -1):

Did you try using the escaped version (ie. `` \'e ,\`a `` ...) ? Without any MWE it will be hard to help you more than this.